# Conditional probability estimation in multinomial regression?

Tags: conditional-probability, multinomial-distribution

I have been analyzing data where the response consists in ordered categories (6) of damage to structures, with a number of damage predictors, thus I have been using multinomial regression.

However, the model can be improved. I know that the probability of a given structure to be at damage level 6 will have an influence on the lower damage levels. This is because, damage level 6 corresponds to collapse of the structure which components become projectiles that most of the time affect the other structures.

My problem is, I am not sure how to include this information in the model. I thought about using something like,
p(ds=DSi ¦ DSn=1) for each previous damage level? DSn being the last damage state, "collapse".

But how to implement this in a GLM?
Or maybe there is another way to do this all together.

Some pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question is hard to understand.  Are the six categories mutually exclusive for a particular structure?  If a structure is collapsed can it also be slightly damaged (or whatever damage level 1 is)?  Also, are you interested in having dependence between damage categories for the same building or between damage categories for adjacent buildings?

Comment: The six categories correspond to an increase in damage level, which I are mutually exclusive: 1 - No damage, 2 - minor, 3 - moderate, 4 - major, 5 - complete, 6 - collapse.

Comment: "complete" and "collapse" may sound like they overlap, however they dont because with complete damage the columns however damaged, are still standing whereas with collapse they 're gone. To answer the second point, a structure that has collapsed will be classified as collapsed, one that has moderate damage will only be classified as such(even though logically each structure would have had to be at the previous damage level). so one single structure can only be at one damage state.

Comment: Finally, what I am interested in as you mentioned is dependence between damage categories for adjacent buildings (not for the same building) - hope that makes sense.

Comment: OK, so you want something like an ordered probit, but with errors which have spatial autocorrelation.  I don't know of such a model off the top of my head, but I will look around.  It may take several days, though.

Comment: I see. I am not in a hurry - this is something I would like to implement at some point. Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Comment: Ingrid, sorry to be so long getting back to you.  The method you want is described in this paper: http://www.ce.utexas.edu/prof/kockelman/public_html/TRB08DSOPmodel.pdf.  I don't think there is a nice, canned routine for estimating the model, however.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks for your time and research on this!